# Android - Asynctask always timing out in android 4.1.1 (Galaxy Tab 2)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timeoutexception

I have a very strange problem.

My app uses an async task to make an http request.
Everything works fine in lower versions, but when I test on a Samsung galaxy Tab 2 with Android 4.1.1 the asynctask ALWAYS throws a TimeoutException.

Here's how I use the code.

```
try {
    response = new HttpContents(getApplicationContext()).execute(url).get(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // the .get(4000,...) part will force a Timeout after 4 secs, but it doesn't happen in pre-honeycomb. Only in android 4+
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // Log.e("WEB TO EXCEPTION",e.toString());
    return null; // This doesn't matter.
}
```

HttpContents is the External AsyncTaks class (which returns the contents fine).

**On lower android versions I test, I get the response correctly.**

*I'm not running it from the main thread (thus, It doesn't freeze my UI).*

For some reason, the http response is being returned exactly when the exception is being thrown. Is there a problem for an asynk task to be executed inside another asynctask's doInBackground (in android 4.0). Because that's what seems to be the problem to me.

**Why do I get this Timeout Exception ONLY on ICS** and not on lower versions.
It there any known issue regarding this?

Comment: Does the exception have a string field set? What does the Log.e("WEB TO EXCEPTION", e.toString()); print out?

Comment: I've tested using only 1 asynktask, and the UI is being frozen initially until the http response is received. I don't like this. It was working fine on pre honeycomb devices!

Comment: @frogmanx WEB TO EXCEPTION(11460): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException. This is of course, because of the .get(4000....) that I put. I'm forcing the timeout (but this should happen only when there's a network problem). and it doesn't happen on pre-honeycomb.